# Copy Files from S3 SignedURL to GCS Signed URL

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, data-transfer

I am developing a service in which two different cloud storage providers are involved. I am trying to copy data from  S3 bucket to GCS.
To access the data I have been offered signedUrls, and to upload the data to GCS I also have signedUrls available which allow me to write content into a specified storage path;

Is there a possibility to move this data "in cloud"? Downloading from S3 and uploading the content to GCS will create bandwidth problems;

I must also mention that this is a on-demand job and it only moves a small number of files. I can not do a full bucket transfer;

Kind regards

Comment: I dont think that apart from storage transfer and gsutil there are any direct services which may perform a direct migration as stated in the usecase. Will inform here if I find anything. Meanwhile, please explore apache airflow. It has s3togcs operator which may prove helpful if you are willing to develop a small pipeline. Here is the link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/s3_to_gcs.html.

Comment: Why is bandwidth an issue? How large is each file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Skyplane](https://github.com/skyplane-project/skyplane) to move data across clouds object stores. To move a single file from S3 to Google Cloud, you can use the command:

```
skyplane cp gcs://<BUCKET>/<FILE> s3://<BUCKET>/<FILE>
```